# XSD Parser is there a way to omit empty elements?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a really complex xsd and now I have something like that:

```
<xs:element name="name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
```

However when validating this xml I need to write  is there a way to omit minOccurs="0"? so that I don't need to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit `minOccurs="0"`, then the element will have to occur at least one time because the default for `minOcurrs` is 1.

This is different than an empty element.  An empty element looks like this:

```
<name/>
```

or

```
<name></name>
```